# Filter features with multi-table joins in ESRI Silverlight/REST API

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, arcgis-silverlight-api, arcgis-rest-api

We have a rather involved data warehouse (SDE 9.3.1 / Oracle 11g) that contains a single related point feature class. Our (analytical) application should allow users to construct complex, ad hoc queries against the data. In every case there will be joins across numerous (but not always the same) tables; only matching features should show on the map. The REST & Silverlight APIs support a simple `where` clause, which seems to limit our options. Can you recommend a strategy for surmounting this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we will simply create a spatial view using joins. Not elegant.